# C# application in a web browser?

Tags: c#, web

Say I coded some application in C# using visual studio. Is there anyway I can take this application and embed it into a website so folks can use it from a website in the same way I would use it from my desktop?

Comment: Read up on Silverlight.

Comment: Maybe [ClickOnce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce)?

Comment: But I hear that a lot of browsers don't support silverlight and nor does microsoft moving forward. Wouldn't that be a problem moving forward?

Comment: There are two ways afaik: if it's a game Unity Web Player might be a choice, otherwise develop it as a web app and wrap into something like Owin+CefSharp for desktop.

Silverlight is likely to be dead.

Comment: @Craig - Silverlight is a dead end.

Comment: @SteveWellens Oh, I've been *totally* on board with that sentiment since essentially the day Silverlight was released. I'm only surprised it took Microsoft so long to figure that out. The same with Java applets in the browser, the same with Flash, et al.  ;-)  I was just saying that's about the only way you're going to get .NET code running "natively" inside a browser instance.

Comment: @Aldmeri, Destop and Web are different platforms. If your application is a website, it is possible to view in desktop application using controls like web browser in windows forms. WPF also has a similar control to display web pages. I haven't tried it though. But I'm not sure about using desktop applications in a web site

Comment: Well, lets see. Exhibit 1: stackoverflow is a C# app. Exhibit 2: you are using it in a web browser.  I rest my case.

Comment: @JK, in which platform of C#, stack overflow app was developed ?

Comment: @Anand StackOverflow is primarily an ASP.NET app, written using C# on the server, also using a number of other technologies including NoSQL databases on Linux servers for caching/performance. But all that heat and smoke on the back end generates HTML/CSS/JavaScript for the browser. In other words, you absolutely, positively in no remote sense of anything that makes any sense at all, are running a C# app in the browser when you visit StackOverflow. There is no C#/.NET code running in your browser. At all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you coded a console application - **no**.
- If you coded a winforms application - **no**.
- If you coded a WPF application - **yes** 
  Two options:

  1. Migrate it to silver light and it will only work on browsers which can install the silver light plug in. keep in mind that silver light is being disbanded by Microsoft, so it is not considered a recommended practice anymore even by MS. also consider that not everyone would agree to install silver light plugin for their browser.
  2. You can also migrate your WPF to become a browser application - but this will require the client machine to have .Net installed on it - so this is like a replacement solution to what once was achieved by ActiveX technology.

  Main difference between those two options is that the 1st one is cross-platform/cross-browser solution and the 2nd one is not.. however this might change in the future as .net is becoming available to Linux too..
- If you coded ASP.Net - it is already designed for developing web applications.

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but I think the WPF/Browser APP is what you looking for, you can read more about it in [How to: Create a New WPF Browser Application Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb628663(v=vs.90).aspx)

**Edit:**

I thought I'd mention if you have a Console or Winform app that people wish to use remotely (ie via a web browser) don't forget they can use Remote Desktop to access the application. Many large enterprises do this using Citrix. Often this is more practical when the cost of rewriting legacy applications is not feasible.

Comment: UPDATE: The scenario the question describes can be fully covered by the use of Thinfinity VirtualUI https://www.cybelesoft.com/thinfinity/virtualui/csharp-to-the-web/